# How do I get related Model field in Django using the Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models

I think that my problem here is Django specific and not necessarily a reflection on
my understanding of relational databases (hopefully).

I have a Django app that stores information on Contacts. 
With that one table things seemed to work fine.  When I wanted to categorize
the type of relationship - is this a professional relationship, family, friends, etc.
That's when things didn't show up like I wanted.  I finally got the migration to work
with the new table. 
        I'm using python 3 with the latest version of django.  I have a mysql
database.  I want a one to many relationship, where one contact can
be characterized by many categories.  When I work with the django admin
and try to enter a contact, I'm not seeing a field for entering relationship categories.

So, here is my models.py for the contacts app.

```
from django.db import models


class Resource(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  organization = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
  street_line1 = models.CharField("Street Line 1", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
  street_line2 = models.CharField("Street Line 2", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
  zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
  phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
  website = models.URLField(max_length=90, null=True, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s \t%s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.organization)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('last_name',)


class Relationship(models.Model):
  category = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, related_name='category')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.category

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('category',)
```

Thanks in advance for any help,
Bruce

Comment: If you want to edit related `Relationship` instances in the `Resource` admin, then you want to use [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

Comment: What are inlines?  I want to edit a contact ( I use the word Resource as I am influenced by the Semantic Web concepts that say every thing is a "resource").  So, as I enter a contacts information, or update it, I can select one or more categories to describe the relationship.  I've done this with some php framework ORM(s), e.g. Cakephp... just getting stuck with Django models.  One Resource to Many (more than one) Categories.  The documentation seems to suggest this will work.  I tried with the ForeignKey in Resource model and got errors in migration.

Comment: The docs that I linked to explain what inlines are, and give an example how to set them up for a one to many relationship between authors and books.

Comment: Thanks... I just noticed that I have a ManyToMany relationship which someone pointed out on the Google group for Django.  Even after adjusting for that, your suggestion is helpful in that everything works perfectly except when I want to display a Contact/Resource detail page.  I was trying to get the one or more "categories" to show up and it was stumping me.  I think inlines is what I need.